# TypeError: GraphQLObjectType is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, graphql

schema.js

```
const { graphql } = require("graphql");
const _ = require('lodash');

const { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } = graphql;


var books = [
    {name: 'Wind',genre:'Fantasy',id:'1'},
    {name: 'Final',genre:'Fantasy',id:'2'},
    {name: 'Long',genre:'Sci-Fi',id:'3'},
];


const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Book',
fields: ()=>({
    id: {type:GraphQLString},
    name: {type:GraphQLString},
    genre: {type: GraphQLString}
   })
});
```

const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
^

TypeError: GraphQLObjectType is not a constructor

Comment: `GraphQLObjectType` is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graphql import statement should be:

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is that you try to pass fields as a function an not an object in your Type definition.

Try this instead.

```js
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        name: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        genre: {
            type: GraphQLString
        }
    }
});
```